# Powershell script to update displayname error

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

When I try to update the display name of the item am getting the following error. Please let me know how to fix this?

```
            Working
     Please wait, working... unlike you!
       'DisplayName' is a ReadOnly property.
      At C:\inetpub\wwwroot\qablog1\temp\tmp7D8B.ps1:13 char:7
+       $row.DisplayName="fff"
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Script:

```
$AllDining = Get-ChildItem -Path "master://sitecore/content/root/Dining" -Recurse

foreach ( $row in $AllDining ) {
    $row.Editing.BeginEdit();
    $row.DisplayName="fff"
    $row.Editing.EndEdit();
    Write-host "title: " $row["DisplayName"];
}
Write-Log $logInfo
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to update the following line:

```
$row.DisplayName="fff"
```

and replace it with:

```
$row."__Display Name"="fff"
```

You should also probably update your `Write-Host` line as follows:

```
Write-Host "title: " $row."__Display Name"
```

Answer (score 2):

```powershell
$homeItem = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/Home"
$homeItem."__Display Name" = "Sitecore Home"
```

Comment: I didnt get any error but unable to find updated display name in an item

Comment: @sindu the display name field is found in the standard fields of the item